# Terminal sed into .command file

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this script to remove the first 4 lines of every file in a folder if their extension is `.txt`.

I want to be able to place a file.command with this script in the same folder so I can just double click on it and execute it.

So I made a file with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i.bak '1,4d' {} \;
```

If I run the file I have all of my Mac txt files 4 lines removed :(

I thought the `find .` was meant to stay in the same folder ...

How do I fix it in order to have the command run ONLY in the folder the file.command is?

Comment: Mine works well try to run it with `-maxdepth 1` and remove the `sed` part to see the files that will be affected

Comment: Are you running it from the folder in question?

Comment: I made the file in the same folder I have the txts and I double click on it - yes same folder

Comment: Run with `-maxdepth 1` and see what happens

Comment: I tried `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i.bak '1,4d' {} \;`but nothing happens..

Comment: It does work if I run it in the terminal (by typing it in full), while if I open the file.command does not run :(

Comment: Is the file called `file.command` ? and do you have the line `#!/bin/bash` at the top of that file, and did you make the file `executable first`?

Comment: Yes to question 1 and 2, while what is "executable first"?

Comment: from the terminal run `chmod +x file.command` then run it with `./file.command` please do all this from the folder where the file is!

Comment: Ok great! Tku! Post your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i.bak '1,4d' {} \;
```

actually works, the issue were:

1. The created file with the command wasn't made `executable` for that do:

   ```
   chmod +x file.command
   ```
2. Then run the command from the terminal with:

   ```
   ./file.command
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, `find` descends into subdirectories by default.

Do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"          # change directory to the location of the script
for file in *.txt; do         # and iterate over the .txt files
    sed -i.bak '1,4d' "$file"
done
```